# IntelliJ: How to auto highlight variables usage in javascript file

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I really like how IntelliJ highlight variables in my Java class.

Is there a way to enable this feature for the javascript files?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Web Development is most advanced in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/). If I look at a simple JavaScript file in the Ultimate Edition, variables are highlighted by default:

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with JavaScript variable highlighting]

The same file in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition does not have variable highlighting:

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA Community with JavaScript variable highlighting]

If you are using the Community Edition, you could give the Ultimate Edition a try to see whether you like it. JetBrain offers a free 30-day trial of the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: Can I add a plugin to do the same ?

Comment: Perhaps; there are quite a lot of plugins available for JavaScript (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=idea&category_id=50), but I see no automatic usage highlighting for JavaScript there. Another option would be to add it as a custom language (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/category/index?pr=idea&category_id=48), but then you are duplicating a lot of work. The Ultimate Edition would be the superior option for this functionality.